# How to consume Spring Data Rest API response with Retrofit 2 when relationship is empty?

Tags: android, retrofit2, spring-data-rest, hal-json

I am developing Android application and backend is being written using Spring Rest Data.

**Scenario:**

Let's say I want to list user's favorite products. I need to call `GET /v1/users/4/favoriteProducts` providing access token in headers. If user has favoriteProducts, I will get response that looks like this:

```
{
    "links" : [ {
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "BASE_URL/v1/users/4/favoriteProducts",
        "hreflang" : null,
        "media" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "type" : null,
        "deprecation" : null
    } ],
    "content" : [ 
        {PRODUCT},
        {PRODUCT},
        {PRODUCT},
    ]
}
```

And I can deserialize this without problems, I get `HalList` object which contains three products. My Retrofit service call looks like this:

```
@GET("v1/users/{user}/favoriteProducts")
fun favoriteProducts(@Path("user") userId: Int): Call<HalList<Product>>
```

and my `HalList` class:

```
data class HalList<T>(
    @SerializedName("links")
    val links: List<HalLink>,

    @SerializedName("content")
    var content: List<T>
)
```

but if I do not have any favorite products I get something like this:

```
{
    "links" : [ {
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "BASE_URL/v1/users/4/favoriteProducts",
        "hreflang" : null,
        "media" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "type" : null,
        "deprecation" : null
    } ],
   "content" : [ {
       "rel" : null,
       "collectionValue" : true,
       "relTargetType" : "com.example.entity.Product",
       "value" : [ ]
   } ]
}
```

And when I parse this with Retrofit I get `HalList` object with `content` containing one instance of Product class with all values set to 0 or null or false, depending on type, and this makes a problem..

I have wrote this `TypeAdapter` for Gson in order to override content with empty list if it is empty based on json

```
class HalTypeAdapterFactory : TypeAdapterFactory {
    override fun <T : Any?> create(gson: Gson?, type: TypeToken<T>?): TypeAdapter<T> {
        val delegate = gson?.getDelegateAdapter(this, type)!!

        if (!HalReflection.isResource(type?.rawType!!)) {
            return delegate
        }

        return HalTypeAdapter(gson, type, delegate)
    }
}

class HalTypeAdapter<T>(private val gson: Gson, private val type: TypeToken<T>, private val delegate: TypeAdapter<T>) : TypeAdapter<T>() {
    private val basicAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement::class.java)!!

    override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: T) {
        delegate.write(out, value)
    }

    override fun read(`in`: JsonReader?): T {
        val fullJson = basicAdapter.read(`in`)
        val deserialized = delegate.fromJsonTree(fullJson)

        if(type.rawType == HalList::class.java || type.rawType == HalPagedList::class.java) {
            if(fullJson.isJsonObject) {
                val content = fullJson.asJsonObject.getAsJsonArray("content")
                if(content[0].isJsonObject) {
                    val o = content[0].asJsonObject
                    if(o.has("collectionValue") && o.has("relTargetType")) {
                        val field = type.rawType.getDeclaredField("content")
                        field.isAccessible = true
                        field.set(deserialized, listOf<T>())
                        field.isAccessible = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return deserialized
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if this is the right solution and is there any more elegant solution? Also is there anything that can be done on backend in order to return empty list like this:

```
{
    "links" : [ {
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "BASE_URL/v1/users/4/favoriteProducts",
        "hreflang" : null,
        "media" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "type" : null,
        "deprecation" : null
    } ],
   "content" : []
}
```

**EDIT**: Final Solution

I did not like the idea to let Gson's delegate adapter to parse response and then I check json string and use reflection to change it to empty list. I changed my approach to modify json response before deserializing it:

```
class HalTypeAdapterFactory : TypeAdapterFactory {
    override fun <T : Any?> create(gson: Gson?, type: TypeToken<T>?): TypeAdapter<T> {
        val delegate = gson?.getDelegateAdapter(this, type)!!

        if (type?.rawType == HalList::class.java)
            return HalListTypeAdapter(gson, type, delegate)

        return delegate
    }
}

class HalListTypeAdapter<T>(
        private val gson: Gson,
        private val type: TypeToken<T>?,
        private val delegate: TypeAdapter<T>)
    : TypeAdapter<T>() {

    private val basicAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement::class.java)

    override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: T) {
        delegate.write(out, value)
    }

    override fun read(`in`: JsonReader?): T {
        val json = basicAdapter.read(`in`)

        if (json.isJsonObject) {
            val resource = json.asJsonObject
            val content = resource.getAsJsonArray("content")
            if (isEmptyCollection(content)) {
                resource.remove("content")
                resource.add("content", JsonArray())
            }
        }

        return delegate.fromJsonTree(json)
    }

    private fun isEmptyCollection(content: JsonArray): Boolean {
        if (content.size() == 1 && content[0].isJsonObject) {
            val first = content[0].asJsonObject
            return first.has("collectionValue") && first.has("relTargetType")
        }

        return false
    }
}

data class HalList<T>(
        @SerializedName("links")
        val links: List<HalReference>,

        @SerializedName("page")
        val page: HalListPageMeta?,

        @SerializedName("content")
        val content: List<T>
)
```

Comment: Can you provide your `Product` class

Comment: You can tell your backend to send response of content as **"content" : [ ]** . For them its possible to send empty array when no favorite product are there.

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi implementation of Product class has nothing to do with problem, it is just data class with attributes related to Product Entity

Comment: @Nainal What should backend do in order to set **"content": []**?

Comment: @clzola It will be helpful to check for null issue

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi `null`s (default values) are expected because I do not have `collectionValue`, `relTargetType` in **Product class** as they are not part of **Product Entity**, when list of entities is empty Spring Data Rest returns list with one object that says that list is empty... and when list is not empty, when there are products then everything works fine